# Differentiate between directory and file

Tags: ios, objective-c, directory

I'm trying to establish if an array contains directories with the following code:

```
for (NSString *item in folderContents)
{
        NSString *itemPath = [subPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:item];

        BOOL isDirectory;
        if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:subPath isDirectory:&isDirectory])
        {
                   if (isDirectory)
                   {                                
                       NSLog(@"sub-directory: %@", itemPath);
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       NSLog(@"document path: %@", itemPath);
                   }
         }
}
```

Currently the array contains strings representing a directory and a .pdf file but both are logged as directories:

```
sub-directory: /Users/.../Documents/downloads/Notices/folder/test document.pdf
sub-directory: /Users/.../Documents/downloads/Notices/folder/test folder
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: Don't know if it the issue, but you are testing `subPath`, but you print `itemPath`. IIUC, you should use itemPath in your call to the file manager.

Comment: OK, but now it seems you run the test twice on `subPath` both times. Whatever subPath is, that doesn't look like the right way to do it. Is this your actual code?

Comment: @Monolo: The 1st if tests if ANY file exists, the 2nd one, if it is a directory.

Comment: @ReinhardMänner yes, and it does that for both trips around the loop, as far as I can see: `subPath` is never assigned a value in the code, so it must have the same value both times the loop is executed.

Comment: @Robert: Is this your actual code? itemPath is only assigned, but not used...

Comment: @ReinhardMänner: D'oh! Yup - that was the problem. Thank you.

Comment: @Robert: Monolo's first comment is correct. You must use `itemPath` in all places. In particular `fileExistsAtPath:itemPath`.

Comment: Thank you all. Apologies for such an idiotic question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still test subpath, not item path